# View Model coming back mostly null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on adding additional functionality to an ASP.NET MVC app that I inherited from a coworker. For some reason all the properties except `SelectedPartyRole` are `null` in the view model parameter of the `AddParticipant` method on the controller, despite the data coming back from the database previously.

**Model:**

```
public class AddParticipantViewModel
{
    public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartyNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartyName { get; set; }
    public string TaxID { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPartyRole { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ValidPartyRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model TN_IntegrationDashboard.Web.Models.AddParticipantViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddClaimParticipant";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div id="sectionTitle">
    <h2>Add Claim Participant</h2>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<fieldset>
<legend></legend>

<div class="status">@ViewBag.Result</div>
<br /><br />
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style="background-color:#3B4044;color:white;height:45px; vertical-align: central;font-weight:600;">
        <th>Claim Number</th>
        <th>Policy Number</th>
        <th>Party Number</th>
        <th>Party Name</th>
        <th>Tax ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClaimNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PolicyNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PartyNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PartyName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaxID)</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br /><br /><br />
<div>
    <button type="button" id="ShowHide">Select Role</button>
</div>


<br /><br /><br />

<div id="ShowHideUpdateControls" hidden="@(ViewBag.Success = true ? "" : "hidden")">

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style="background-color:#3B4044;color:white;height:45px; vertical-align: central;font-weight:600;">
        <th>Valid Party Roles</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPartyRole,
                                  new SelectList(Model.ValidPartyRoles, "Key", "Value"),
                                  "")</td>
    </tr>
</table>
 <br /><br /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="Save" formaction='@Url.Action("AddParticipant")'>

 }

</div>
</fieldset>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ClaimController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AuthorizeByConfig(RolesAppSettingKey = "", UsersAppSettingKey = "ClaimUpdateAuthorizedUsers")]
    public ActionResult SearchForClaimParticipant()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeByConfig(RolesAppSettingKey = "", UsersAppSettingKey = "ClaimUpdateAuthorizedUsers")]
    public ActionResult SearchForClaim(string claimNumber)
    {
        IClaimManager proxy = CreateClaimManagerProxy();
        var claim = proxy.GetClaim(claimNumber);

        if (claim == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Status = "Claim record not found. Please enter a different claim number.";
            return View("SearchForClaim");
        }
        else
        {
            var modifyClaimViewModel = new ClaimViewModel
            {
                ClaimNumber = claim.ClaimNumber,
                NotificationDate = claim.NotificationDate
            };
            return View("ModifyClaim", modifyClaimViewModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeByConfig(RolesAppSettingKey = "", UsersAppSettingKey = "ClaimUpdateAuthorizedUsers")]
    public ActionResult SearchForClaimParticipant(string claimNumber, string partyNumber)
    {
        IClaimManager claimProxy = CreateClaimManagerProxy();
        IPartyAdminManager partyProxy = CreatePartyAdminManagerProxy();

        var claim = claimProxy.GetClaim(claimNumber);
        var party = partyProxy.GetParty(partyNumber);

        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        if (claim == null)
            string.Concat(errorMessage, "Claim record not found. Please enter a different claim number. ");
        if (party == null)
            string.Concat(errorMessage, "Party record not found. Please enter a different party number.");

        if (errorMessage.Length > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Status = errorMessage;
            return View("SearchForClaimParticipant");
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> roles = partyProxy.GetPartyRoles();
            string partyName = string.Empty;

            if (party.BusinessName == null || party.BusinessName == string.Empty)
                partyName = string.Concat(party.FirstName, " ", string.Concat(party.MiddleName, " ") ?? string.Empty, party.LastName);
            else
                partyName = party.BusinessName;

            var addParticipantViewModel = new AddParticipantViewModel
            {
                ClaimNumber = claim.ClaimNumber,
                PolicyNumber = claim.PolicyNumber,
                PartyNumber = partyNumber,
                PartyName = partyName,
                TaxID = party.TaxID,
                ValidPartyRoles = roles
            };
            return View("AddClaimParticipant", addParticipantViewModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeByConfig(RolesAppSettingKey = "", UsersAppSettingKey = "ClaimUpdateAuthorizedUsers")]
    public ActionResult AddParticipant(AddParticipantViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IClaimManager proxy = CreateClaimManagerProxy();
            string result = proxy.AddParticpant(viewModel.ClaimNumber, viewModel.PartyNumber, viewModel.SelectedPartyRole);
            ViewBag.Result = result;
        }
        return View("AddClaimParticipant");
    }

    private static IIntegrationDashboardManager CreateDashboardManagerProxy()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IIntegrationDashboardManager> _channelFactory;
        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IIntegrationDashboardManager>("*");
        IIntegrationDashboardManager channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    private static IClaimManager CreateClaimManagerProxy()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IClaimManager> _channelFactory;
        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IClaimManager>("*");
        IClaimManager channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    private static IPartyAdminManager CreatePartyAdminManagerProxy()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IPartyAdminManager> _channelFactory;
        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPartyAdminManager>("*");
        IPartyAdminManager channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        return channel;
    }
}
```

I have compared the code to the code I copied from and didn't notice anything different outside of using the Dictionary in the view model. I also tried commenting out the Dictionary in each layer and checking the view model parameter while debugging, but everything was coming back null still. I think I'm at the end of my MVC knowledge, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have only a SELECT element (for `SelectedPartyRole`) in the form which you are submitting. When the form is submitted, the model binder will read the request body of the submitted form and bind to your view model property which is your action method parameter.

If you want to send more property values, you need to keep them in  form input elements inside the form. If you do not want the user to see it, you may keep them in hidden input fields.

The `Html.HiddenFor` helper method can be used to generate the hidden input fields.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddParticipant","Claim")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.ClaimNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.PolicyNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.PartyNumber)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPartyRole,
                                  new SelectList(Model.ValidPartyRoles, "Key", "Value"),
                                  "")
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />    
}
```

Keep in mind that, any data coming from the client could be bad data. So the rule of thumb is, **never trust data coming from client** and always validate it as needed. User can simply update the hidden input field value using browser dev tools and send you wrong data. So always validate on server side before doing important stuff.

Another option is to have a unique id (primary key of this entity) in your form and inside your httppost action, get the entity again from the db/any persistence mechanism, using this id and use that.  This will be more safe than relying on client side data.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you!